# Failed to Start Light Display Manager

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux

1. I was trying to install Deepin desktop environment in Arch, following these [instructions](http://www.ostechnix.com/install-deepin-desktop-environment-arch-linux/), everything works perfect but I noticed that my Gnome environment started to work slowly, for instance, the Chrome browser shows some lag in the scroll and the windows show some lag between maximize and minimize.
2. I removed Deepin and tried to get back my config. I removed the greeter from `lightdm.conf` and reran `systemctl start lightdm.service`, `systemctl enable lightdm.service`
3. When I restarted my Arch boot in terminal mode (not GUI) I probably made some mistake and changed some `lightdm` configuration because when I type `systemctl start lightdm.service` the terminal said "file not found"
4. After rebooting the OS it entered into a loop and infinite job start task. I will explain this:

   When I change "quiet splash" for "text" in my GRUB startup menu, I can check that several services run OK but the message "Failed to start Light Display Manager" appears. It also shows that many jobs are running, some fail because they exceeds the time limit, but there are some than don't have a time limit.

A start job is running for dev-disk-by.

I can't enter in my console mode, I suspect than it is because all these jobs are running and they are jobs with no time limit.

I think that first I need to start the console without all these running jobs, but that doesn't allow me to enter into the terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>

How can I boot into terminal mode with the minimum services running, that is to avoid those jobs than don't allow me run the terminal.

I suppose after that I can change my `lightdm` file, maybe remove and reinstall it could be a solution, so I suppose than I could have some possible solutions, but I'm not sure how to boot in terminal mode similar to the Windows recovery console, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GRUB, edit the command and add the [runlevel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SysVinit/runlevels) parameter 3.
This will allow you to start without the display manager and access directly to your terminal.
Then you would be able to modify your ligthdm config with vi or nano.
Or you can more simply completely uninstall ligthdm, then install it with a fresh config.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you need to the specific question above, but I ended up here when I searched the internet for "Failed to start Light Display Manager", so maybe this can be helpful for other seekers.

I had the exact same issue today.

Got a HP ProBook 450 G6, downloaded BunsenLabs to install it from a USB key. No apparent issues during install, but at the first boot it gave the same error

```
"Failed to start Light Display Manager"
```

so no windows manager.

I pressed <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F1</kbd> to go in a terminal mode, logged in with my user/password and updated the system:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

rebooted the system afterwards and the windows manager started fine now.

Hope this might help someone in the future